# Apple app site association subdomain setup

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

Let's try to make an example that would make most sense to explain my problem. Let's say I have my app available on `example.com` and also created few universal links like `example.com/application` that when clicked from a phone device open inside the app if it's installed. This works fine.

Now can I make subdomain, something like `app.example.com` where if you click on it, it will also open inside the application. So pretty much any path from `app.example.com/*` should open within the app if installed.

What would be the process of doing this. Do I have to create a subdomain, can this be done from from adding associated domains, how would my `apple-app-site-association` file look?

I know my question is a big vague, but just looking at some starting pointers or documentation around doing this. Hopefully it's enough for someone to give some advice

Comment: The documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains seems to cover how to handle subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. Deep link domains and applications are in many-to-many relation. Each of your domains should provide association manifest that mentions each of your apps that can work with links on that domain.

If you have two domains `example.com` and `app.example.com` and a single application, then both of these links:

- https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
- https://app.example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

should point to a file like that (replace `XXXXXXXXXX.com.example.app` with actual app id):

```json
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "XXXXXXXXXX.com.example.app"
                ],
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {"/": "/*"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "XXXXXXXXXX.com.example.app"
        ]
    }
}
```

In your iOS project Entitlements.plist, you should add each of your domains explicitly:

```xml
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:example.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:example.com</string>
        <string>applinks:app.example.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:app.example.com</string>
    </array>
...
```

or using a wildcard:

```xml
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:example.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:example.com</string>
        <string>applinks:*.example.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:*.example.com</string>
    </array>
...
```

Comment: Hello, I did find your answer here, and it seem you are a master of subdomains for aasa. Could you look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77221023/2725435) question here? ;) Thank you very much.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk yes, I've seen this behaviour when iOS suggests credentials autocompletion from another subdomains, but I don't have any solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this JSON inside my **apple-app-site-association** file.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "your appID and bundle identifier",
                "paths": ["*", "/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

you can also check this example (by Apple)  for adding subdomains in your **apple-app-site-association** file.

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app", "ABCDE12345.com.example.app2" ],
             "components": [
               {
                  "#": "no_universal_links",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL with a fragment that equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link."
               },
               {
                  "/": "/buy/*",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /buy/."
               },
               {
                  "/": "/help/website/*",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /help/website/ and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link."
               },
               {
                  "/": "/help/*",
                  "?": { "articleNumber": "????" },
                  "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /help/ and that has a query item with name 'articleNumber' and a value of exactly four characters."
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app" ]
   },

    "appclips": {
        "apps": ["ABCED12345.com.example.MyApp.Clip"]
    }
}
```

for more information, you can check on this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains